SVG file not being used as CSS mask
I want to use an SVG file as a mask for some images. However, it is not being used, and instead hides the entire image. I included it separately to check whether the path was wrong, but as an image it loads fine. I also checked it in different browsers, with and without quotes, and added some headers in the SVG, but nothing.
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #testDiv
            {
                display: inline-block;
                -webkit-mask:url("1.svg");
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="testDiv">
            <img id="test" src="1.png" style="height: 250px; width: 1500px; object-fit: cover;">
        </div>
        <img src="1.svg">
    </body>
</html>

SVG:
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="250px" width="1500px">
    <text x="0" y="180" font-family="Cambria, sans-serif" font-size="250">
        Text masking
    </text>
</svg>

Output (The top is empty, but it should show a masked image.):

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.
Also I should say that this works fine (I cut and formatted it to make it clearer, but in the code it's a single-line string with no line breaks.):
-webkit-mask:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="250px" width="1500px">
    <text id="mask" x="0" y="180" font-family="Cambria, sans-serif" font-size="250">
    Test masking
    </text>
</svg>');

Edit: I put it in "in-line" CSS and it shows the preview, so the SVG is being found, but it's not being applied:


Are you opening the HTML file directly? If so, it might just work if you use a static server.

@Nikk I put in localhost but it looks the same.

As commented by @Nikk: it won't work if you open it directly (in file mode). Testing it on a local server worked flawlessly. Also double check your paths/Urls. The mask svg URL needs to be relative to the final output directory of your CSS file (especially relevant if you're using preprocessors like scss or bundlers that may output a compiled css to another) I guess your main.css is not in your root directory.

Use "-webkit-mask-image" instead:
-webkit-mask-image:url("1.svg");


Not exactly "instead". But you're right CSS masks unfortunately still require some browser prefixes. So you should better use both albeit Firefox was generous to also accept the webkit vendor prefix by default. the more specific mask-image should also run without prefixes.

@herrstrietzel The problem was that I was using "-webkit-mask", so it replaces that. In the version without prefixes it would be as you say.

Sorry, I see. Frankly, the mask related properties can be quite confusing. However, I highly recommend to define prefixed and unprefixed properties as we can't be sure when browsers drop support or prefer the unprefixed versions ... admittedly, not critical since most notably chromium based browsers are not even based on webkit but on blink ... prefixes we're annoying right from the beginning =)

There are a couple of possibilities here:

The request to 1.svg is resulting in a 4xx status of some sort (for instance, a 404), because the server is not able to honour the request
The MIME type of this file is incorrect when it gets served. If it isn't image/svg+xml, then the browser won't know what to do with it.

Your next step here is to look at the developer console for the request and see what's up.

The lower text is the SVG itself, it seems to be loaded properly, here are no errors in the console, and I can't find any requests (this is a local HTML). What is the syntax to set the MIME type? Turning it into an HTML and adding a meta tag with the information didn't have an effect.

Are you accessing your page via the file:// protocol or http://? If you open the Network tab of your browser, click on the 1.svg request and look for the Content-Type header, what does it say?
